# How to append to Python list in a dict without having to initialize the list?

Tags: python, loops

In PHP, I can do this

```
$a['name'][] = 'el1';
```

In Python, I have to do this:

```
a = {}
a['name'] = []
a['name'].append('el1')
```

The problem with the above approach is that I'm losing the value of `a['name']` in the next loop when iterating because I'm reinitializing `a['name']` to an empty list .

Is there any way to append items to a list without having to initialize with an empty list first?

Comment: dictionaries won't contain duplicate keys.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) module:

```
from collections import defaultdict
a = defaultdict(list)
```

With this setting, the module initializes to an empty list on first access, so you can just do:

```
 a['name'].append('el1')
```

and not worry about it.

Hope that helps!

Comment: It might a Python v3 problem, but the above does not work and even if it did, you would still have to do listname = defaultdict(list) for every list you wanted to use, which does not solve the OP.

Comment: Tested on python 3.8.12 still works properly. 
by the way, listname = defaultdict(list) does not create a list. It creates a dictionary of lists. Which solves exactly the original problem, as you can create both dictionary entries (name of lists) and append elements to lists without initializing anything.

Answer (score 8):

So, the way that you've phrased it no, you can only `append` to something that exists. That said, you don't have to append to this at all, you could do this:

```
a = {'name': ['el1']}
```

No need to manually create your structure like that.

If you want to check for the existence of a key before trying to append to a list you can do this:

```
a.setdefault('name', []).append('el1')
```

The second argument to `get` also gives you a default, saying if `name` doesn't exist, append to an empty list instead.

Comment: You really want `setdefault` here. `a.setdefault("name", []).append("el1")`

Comment: @kindall I... only just realized what OP was asking.

Comment: Whenever I see `.setdefault`, I ask myself ... Do I really want to be seeing `collections.defaultdict` instead?

Comment: You don't need to assign back to `a['name']`; in fact, it's wrong to do so, because now you've overwritten the value of `a['name']` with the return value of `append` (i.e., `None`).

Answer (score 3):

I think you're asking for something like this:

```
a = {}

if 'name' not in a:
    a['name'] = []

a['name'].append('el1')
```

Also, you might want to look at [Python's defaultdict datatype](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to see if that would be better for your purposes.

Comment: This is one way to do it, without seeing your full code for more context, I'd say this decent, Rachel Sanders' excellent answer below also gives more info on the defaultdict. I'd say between these two, it depends on your taste.

Comment: @IsabellaWilcox It might help if you were a little clearer in your question about exactly what you're looking for, but the above code is not extremely pythonic